# Is there any way to see weapons damage?

Tags: fallout-tactics

When i click on weapon in my inventory the only stats i am given are: minimal strenght needed to use the weapon, what ammo type the weapon is using and how much it weights.

So far i haven't found any way to get more stats shown. Is that even possible? If not is there a mod that would allow me to see more stats for weapons, because i really don't want to bother playing the game if I'd have to go check weapon damage on wiki everytime I'm gonna buy new weapon, or decide on which weapon to use from the ones i picked up.

Comment: It's not really worth powergaming on. Just pick a weapon that looks cool; that's how the game was designed to be played. There's only a short period of time when you can actually choose which ones you buy. Around the mid game, you'll face up against some really powerful big guns and energy weapons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to know how much damage the weapon will do, is by equipping it. You'll be able to see the damage range of the weapon on the stats that appears in your inventory.

You should be able to see twice damage range, from memory:
- the first one is for the punch slot
- the second one is for the kick slot

The screenshot that follows is from the original Fallout games, but it's basically the same:

[Inventory screenshot](http://s.pro-gmedia.com/videogamer/media/images/pub/large/weapons.jpg)

You can also see how much your armor protect you against the different kind of damage in the same screen

Comment: Damn, that's pretty bad and dissapointing system. I'd have to buy all weapons, check them out and then load and buy the ones whos stats i like the most, or just check the wiki like i did before. Thanks.